# powershell Invoke-WebRequest WebSession not working

Tags: powershell, web, httpwebrequest

I can't get the following code to work. It appears to log in but then returns the login page with $response. I am guessing it has something to do with the postbacks?  Any way to get around that?  Thanks!

```
$login = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.sqlpass.org/UserLogin.aspx' -SessionVariable sqlpass
$login.Forms[0].Fields["txtUsername_14615"] = 'myuser'
$login.Forms[0].Fields["txtPassword_14615"] = 'mypass'
$response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.sqlpass.org/UserLogin.aspx' -WebSession $sqlpass -Method POST -Body $login
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an event target field that also needs to be set, also the POST needs a different URL, i tested the solution below and it works:

```
$login = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.sqlpass.org/UserLogin.aspx' -SessionVariable sqlpass
$form = $login.Forms[0]
$form.Fields["__EVENTTARGET"] = "UserLogin"
$form.Fields["txtUsername_14615"] = 'myuser'
$form.Fields["txtPassword_14615"] = 'mypass'
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'http://www.sqlpass.org/UserLogin.aspx?returnurl=%2fdefault.aspx' -WebSession $sqlpass -Method POST -Body $form.Fields
```

Note: Just as a side note, you can use Web Debugging proxies like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) to debug issues like this, which is exactly what i did.

Comment: @Snowdogging no problem, a couple of months ago I was asking similar questions, we all have to start somewhere! :)