# invoke-webrequest Login to Adobe.com

Tags: powershell, webrequest

So, i am trying to log into Adobe.com with Invoke-webrequest and am not getting an error but am not able to log in.  I have installed Fiddler to get all the right fields for the login form.  So, here is my script that doesn't log in but doesn't give an error.

```
$wr = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://adobeid-na1.services.adobe.com/renga-idprovider/pages/login?callback=https%3A%2F%2Fims-na1.adobelogin.com%2Fims%2Fadobeid%2FSunbreakWebUI1%2FAdobeID%2Ftoken%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccounts.adobe.com%252F%2523from_ims%253Dtrue%2526old_hash%253D%2526api%253Dauthorize%2526reauth%253Dforce&client_id=SunbreakWebUI1&scope=AdobeID%2Copenid%2Csunbreak%2Cacct_mgmt_webui%2Cgnav%2Cadditional_info.account_type%2Csao.cce_private%2Ccreative_cloud%2Cread_countries_regions%2Cupdate_profile.password%2Cadditional_info.roles%2Cupdate_profile.optionalAgreements%2Cupdate_profile.change_password%2Cadditional_info.social%2Csocial.link%2Cunlink_social_account%2Creauthenticated&denied_callback=https%3A%2F%2Fims-na1.adobelogin.com%2Fims%2Fdenied%2FSunbreakWebUI1%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccounts.adobe.com%252F%2523from_ims%253Dtrue%2526old_hash%253D%2526api%253Dauthorize%2526reauth%253Dforce%26response_type%3Dtoken&display=web_v2&relay=e4a0063e-836e-4c51-8a39-4016d0f8ad8e&locale=en_US&flow_type=token&client_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fims-na1.adobelogin.com%2Fims%2Fredirect%2FSunbreakWebUI1%3Fclient_redirect%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccounts.adobe.com%252F%2523from_ims%253Dtrue%2526old_hash%253D%2526api%253Dauthorize%2526reauth%253Dforce&idp_flow_type=login&reauthenticate=force' -SessionVariable adobe

#These are the login values that i got from Fiddler
$vals = @{
    authSrc='AdobeID';
    callback=$($wr.Forms[0].Fields.adobeid_callback);
    #client_id=$($wr.Forms[0].Fields.adobeid_client_id);
    client_id='SunbreakWebUI1';
    client_redirect=$($wr.Forms[0].Fields.adobeid_client_redirect);
    denied_callback=$($wr.Forms[0].Fields.adobeid_denied_callback);
    display=$($wr.Forms[0].Fields.adobeid_display);
    flow=$($wr.Forms[0].Fields.adobeid_flow);
    flow_type=$($wr.Forms[0].Fields.adobeid_flow_type);
    force_marketing_permission=$($wr.Forms[0].Fields.adobeid_force_marketing_permission);
    idp_flow_type=$($wr.Forms[0].Fields.adobeid_idp_flow_type);
    is_reauthenticating='false';
    locale=$($wr.Forms[0].Fields.adobeid_locale);
    page_name='SignIn_Form';
    password='MyPassword1';
    relay=$($wr.Forms[0].Fields.adobeid_relay);
    scope=$($wr.Forms[0].Fields.adobeid_scope);
    username='myname@sample.com';
    vi=''
}
#Now I am logging into adobe with a post.
$wr2 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://adobeid-na1.services.adobe.com/renga-idprovider/pages/login.do' -WebSession $adobe -Method Post -Body $vals
```

all of these urls and form values were pulled from Fiddler.
Anyone have thoughts on what i am missing? or how to troubleshoot the script?

My $vals hash table looks like this.

```
Name                           Value                                                                                                                                                 
----                           -----                                                                                                                                                 
relay                          e4a0063e-836e-4c51-8a39-4016d0f8ad8e                                                                                                                  
username                       myname@sample.com                                                                                                                          
vi                                                                                                                                                                                   
scope                          AdobeID,openid,sunbreak,acct_mgmt_webui,gnav,additional_info.account_type,sao.cce_private,creative_cloud,read_countries_regions,update_profile.pass...
is_reauthenticating            false                                                                                                                                                 
password                       MyPassword1                                                                                                                                              
authSrc                        AdobeID                                                                                                                                               
denied_callback                https://ims-na1.adobelogin.com/ims/denied/SunbreakWebUI1?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.adobe.com%2F%23from_ims%3Dtrue%26old_hash%3D%26api%3Da...
display                        web_v2                                                                                                                                                
idp_flow_type                  login                                                                                                                                                 
locale                         en_US                                                                                                                                                 
force_marketing_permission     false                                                                                                                                                 
flow_type                      token                                                                                                                                                 
page_name                      SignIn_Form                                                                                                                                           
callback                       https://ims-na1.adobelogin.com/ims/adobeid/SunbreakWebUI1/AdobeID/token?redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.adobe.com%2F%23from_ims%3Dtrue%26old_ha...
client_redirect                https://ims-na1.adobelogin.com/ims/redirect/SunbreakWebUI1?client_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Faccounts.adobe.com%2F%23from_ims%3Dtrue%26old_hash%3D%26ap...
flow                           true                                                                                                                                                  
client_id                      SunbreakWebUI1
```

I have also tried converting to JSON and passing that without success.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Where is the `websession $adobe` in the code? Thats what creates the session. 
Basically you have create the `sessionvariable $adobe` then you should use it to get in to that session using `websession $adobe`... 

Check [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13756065/powershell-invoke-webrequest-websession-not-working) for reference.

Comment: I have it at the end of the very long first line, "-SessionVariable adobe".  So, I'm a bit perplexed.  I think Adobe has some hidden something going on that my novice eyes are not seeing.

I tested the same set of commands against a personal website of mine (obviously different login form) and was able to log in.  So, again I think Adobe has some special sauce in the background.

Answer (score 0):

I've just figured this out. You were actually really close. Hope this helps:

```
$r = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://adobeid-na1.services.adobe.com/renga-idprovider/pages/login?callback=https%3A%2F%2Fims-na1.adobelogin.com%2Fims%2Fadobeid%2FSunbreakWebUI1%2FAdobeID%2Ftoken%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccounts.adobe.com%252F%2523from_ims%253Dtrue%2526old_hash%253D%2526api%253Dauthorize%2526reauth%253Dforce&client_id=SunbreakWebUI1&scope=AdobeID%2Copenid%2Csunbreak%2Cacct_mgmt_webui%2Cgnav%2Cadditional_info.account_type%2Csao.cce_private%2Ccreative_cloud%2Cread_countries_regions%2Cupdate_profile.password%2Cadditional_info.roles%2Cupdate_profile.optionalAgreements%2Cupdate_profile.change_password%2Cadditional_info.social%2Csocial.link%2Cunlink_social_account%2Creauthenticated&denied_callback=https%3A%2F%2Fims-na1.adobelogin.com%2Fims%2Fdenied%2FSunbreakWebUI1%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccounts.adobe.com%252F%2523from_ims%253Dtrue%2526old_hash%253D%2526api%253Dauthorize%2526reauth%253Dforce%26response_type%3Dtoken&display=web_v2&relay=e4a0063e-836e-4c51-8a39-4016d0f8ad8e&locale=en_US&flow_type=token&client_redirect=https%3A%2F%2Fims-na1.adobelogin.com%2Fims%2Fredirect%2FSunbreakWebUI1%3Fclient_redirect%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Faccounts.adobe.com%252F%2523from_ims%253Dtrue%2526old_hash%253D%2526api%253Dauthorize%2526reauth%253Dforce&idp_flow_type=login&reauthenticate=force' -SessionVariable Adobe
$form = $r.Forms[0]
$form.Fields["adobeid_username"] = $username
$form.Fields["adobeid_password"] = $password
$r2 = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://adobeid-na1.services.adobe.com/renga-idprovider/pages/login.do" -WebSession $Adobe -Method Post -Body $form.Fields
```